# Dimensions of the pages

Tags: margins, geometry

I have used the simple dimensions `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to scale all pages of my document with the `geometry` package.

Suppose I want a few pages with different scaling and a few pages with different scaling in the same article. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use the `\newgeometry{...}` to change the geometry mid-document and `\restoregeometry` to restore the settings you made in the preamble.

Comment: Are you restricted in terms of the package usage (you mention this is for an article)? If not, are you concerned about the flow of the document (since `\newgeometry` would force a break of the page)? The [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package could assist in flowing content from one page to the next using a different layout (margin- and text-block wise).